# Advanced query with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have been trying for some time now to figure out how to get this query made with Laravel Eloquent.

Query:

```
DB::select('SELECT
    n.id,
    n.parent_id,
    n.name,
    n.file,
    n.created_at AS ts,
    f.mime,
    f.extension,
    IF(ch.id, 1, 0) AS dirs 
FROM nodes AS n 
LEFT JOIN nodes AS ch ON ch.parent_id=n.id
LEFT JOIN files AS f
    ON n.file = f.id
WHERE n.parent_id=?
GROUP BY n.id',array($path));
```

I have my model `Node` which is using table `nodes` and I have a method `nodefile()` for my `Node` model, including `return $this->belongsTo('NodeFile');` which is the other module I need to join. The `NodeFile` module is using the table `files` and those two are bound on the `nodes.file` and the `files.id`.

This is what I got so far:

```
Node::with(
    array('nodefile'=>function($query){
        $query->select('mime','extension');
    })
)->where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get(array(
    'id', 'parent_id', 'name', 'file', 'created_at AS nts'
));
```

But I still need the `IF(ch.id,1,0) AS dirs` in my query. And haven't done the self join aswell.

Anyone have any idea how to do this in the best possible way?

Comment: Why can't you keep it in raw query()? ORMs were invented to *simplify* things, not to make you bang your head against table. What can be ORMified - all right, make it through Eloquent. But some queries aren't intended to be run with ORMS. So, don't torture them then

Comment: You can do a `$query->select(DB::raw(...))`

Comment: You didn't provide enough information about your relationship, actually confused about `IF(ch.id, 1, 0) AS dirs`, so can't help but you may check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-model-relationship#.U0QUFvmSySo), it is about self join using `Eloquent` relationship technique.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, because I want to take usage of the Eloquent [SoftDelete](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: @MarkBaker, I want to take usage of Eloquent [SoftDelete](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting) which isn't there for a raw DB query.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I use `IF(ch.id, 1, 0) AS dirs` to make a if statement inside my select query. `dirs` will come out as `1` if `ch.id` exists, if not then `dirs` will be `0`.

`ch` is my alias for my joining own table checking if there is any rows which have the current row as `parent_id`.

Comment: I know what `IF(ch.id, 1, 0) AS dirs` will produce but not sure what you are checking with it because `nodes.id` relates to `nodes.parent_id`, `ch/child nodes` will always contain an `id` but maybe not a `parent_id`, what is the initial value for `parent_id` when it has no parent related ?

Comment: You can add individual "raw" select columns, that won't adversely affect softdelete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed using the following piece of code.

```
Node::
  leftjoin('files','files.id','=','nodes.file')
->leftjoin('nodes AS ch','ch.parent_id','=','nodes.id')
->where('nodes.id','=',$path)
->groupBy('id')
->get(array(
    'nodes.id',
    'nodes.parent_id',
    'nodes.name',
    'nodes.file',
    'nodes.created_at AS nts',
    'files.mime',
    'files.extension',
    'ch.id AS dirs'
  ));
```

Thanks to @MarkBarker for the idea of making it raw, which helped me getting to this solution.